# NiFi in docker container fails to talk to kafka: TimoutException, kafkacat ist working just fine

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, streaming, apache-nifi, timeoutexception

I have set up NiFi (1.11.4) & Kafka(2.5) via docker (docker-compose file below, actual NiFi flow definition https://github.com/geoHeil/streaming-reference).
When trying to follow up on basic getting started tutorials (such as https://towardsdatascience.com/big-data-managing-the-flow-of-data-with-apache-nifi-and-apache-kafka-af674cd8f926) which combine processors such as:

- generate flowfile (CSV)
- update attribute
- PublishKafka2.0

I run into issues of timeoutException:

```
nifi_1            | 2020-06-10 11:15:47,311 ERROR [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] o.a.n.p.k.pubsub.PublishKafkaRecord_2_0 PublishKafkaRecord_2_0[id=959f0e64-0172-1000-0000-0000650181a4] Failed to send StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=944464e4-94ea-48dc-89fa-d19c34f163e7,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1591771086044-1, container=default, section=1], offset=227962, length=422],offset=0,name=c8dd1dd2-0ffe-4875-9d45-902ea331c210,size=422] to Kafka: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 64 record(s) for test-0: 30029 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
nifi_1            | org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 64 record(s) for test-0: 30029 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
nifi_1            | 2020-06-10 11:15:47,311 ERROR [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] o.a.n.p.k.pubsub.PublishKafkaRecord_2_0 PublishKafkaRecord_2_0[id=959f0e64-0172-1000-0000-0000650181a4] Failed to send StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=944464e4-94ea-48dc-89fa-d19c34f163e7,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1591771086044-1, container=default, section=1], offset=227962, length=422],offset=0,name=c8dd1dd2-0ffe-4875-9d45-902ea331c210,size=422] to Kafka: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 64 record(s) for test-0: 30029 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
nifi_1            | org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 64 record(s) for test-0: 30029 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

However, a:

```
kafkacat -C -b localhost:9092 -t test #starts listener
kafkacat -P -b localhost:9092 -t test #starts producer
```

pipes events just fine through the kafka instance.

The docker-compose file looks like:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:1.11.4
    ports:
      - 8080:8080 # Unsecured HTTP Web Port
    environment:
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=8080
      - NIFI_CLUSTER_IS_NODE=true
      - NIFI_CLUSTER_NODE_PROTOCOL_PORT=8082
      - NIFI_ZK_CONNECT_STRING=zookeeper:2181
      - NIFI_ELECTION_MAX_WAIT=1 min
    links:
      - broker
      - zookeeper
    volumes:
      - ./for_nifi/conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
  zookeeper: #https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/5.5.0-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml#L5
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
```

Comment: What host&port are you using in NiFi to connect to Kafka?

Comment: I use the broker:9092, i.e. the DNS of docker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong port to connect to the broker. By connecting to `9092` you connect to the listener that advertises `localhost:9092` to the client for subsequent connections. That's why it works when you use `kafkacat` from your local machine (because 9092 is exposed to your local machine)

If you use `broker:29092` then the broker will give the client the correct address for the connection (i.e. `broker:29092`).

To understand more about advertised listeners see [this blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-10&utm_term=rmoff-devx)

Comment: Great blog post. But there, you also only use 9092, never 29092. However, I can confirm: indeed your solution works just great.

Comment: Glad you got it working. In that post the broker may well be configured differently from yours, which is why the port numbers might not match up with what you're using.